# How to copy empty directory to output in visual studio?

Tags: .net, c, visual-studio

I would like to generate an empty folder in my bin, however you can't apply "copy always" to folders, only to items within folders.
Is there a cleaner way to do this than to create an empty file in the folder and tag it with copy always? I'm using VS 12 and this is for a WPF C# app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a **Post-Build event.**
Right click on your project file and select **Properties** then **Build Events**

In the empty text box for the Post-Build event, type your command line to copy/create the files in your destination directory.

You can also call a batch file or use some predefined macros that contains the names of your working folders.

And you can define the exact context in which your command should run (On successuful build ....)

Sorry, I have no time to test, however I hope to give you a start in the right direction:

Create a batch file named Test.cmd, add these lines and save it in the solution folder

```
rem ---------------------
rem %1 = $(ProjectDir) 
rem %2 = $(SolutionDir) 
rem %3 = $(TargetDir) 
rem ---------------------
C:
CD %2
IF NOT EXIST %3\test1. md %3\test1
xcopy %1 %3\test1
```

Then in the Post-Build event call it with

```
$(SolutionDir)test.cmd $(ProjectDir) $(SolutionDir) $(TargetDir)
```

Comment: Do you have a sample post build event i could paste to create a folder named "test" in the output dir whichever it is? (that works debug release and any other config i may need including other platforms etc)?

Comment: Sorry didn't see you updated the answer, thanks should start me right :)

Answer (score 1):

You can edit the `.csproj` file directly with:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <None Remove="MyEmptyFolder\" />
</ItemGroup>

<ItemGroup>
  <Folder Include="MyEmptyFolder\">
    <CopyToOutputDirectory>Always</CopyToOutputDirectory>
  </Folder>
</ItemGroup>
```

You can easily come to this solution by adding a file inside the folder, mark it as always copy (it will modify the csproj) and then delete it and remove the file name from the csproj while keeping only folder.

Comment: It didn't worked for me. Using VS 2022.

Comment: Maybe I had a typo somewhere... did you tried the walkthrough I wrote below?

Comment: Yep, replacing `Content` with `Folder` like you posted. But with no success. I end up doing it directly in C# at startup (`if (!Directory.Exists(savesFolder))
                    Directory.CreateDirectory(savesFolder);`), though I'm sure it can be done in project setting too (involving some shell command i guess).